# NSIS installer : how can i get location of executable installed earlier via different installer?

Tags: nsis

I am using NSIS to create installer for my application. However I need path of some application(i.e python ) during run time of NSIS-installer. I am unable to figure out some direct way from NSIS.

Comment: What exactly is NSISW?

Comment: How are we supposed to know how to help when you provide so little information about this application. Is it registered in the registry somewhere? What is the name of this application?

Comment: My installer install third party application i.e call third party installer to install python and then launch script which has to use the python from this latest installation to launch the scripts. I  hope it is more clear now.

Comment: No, it is not clear, you have not even told us the name of this application. How are we supposed to know if it writes any information you can read to find its path when we don't even know which application we should be investigating?

Comment: here are all the details. there are two step in installation . first installing docker in window. Once it is done , installer call certain powershell scripts    which in turn create desired container for user to use. Powershell script need to run boot2docker_start first (which is actually .sh script and installed duing docker installation) to create boot2docker-vm . My question , is whether it is possible for me to know installation path of docker in windows during run time via nsis scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their [documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20150622105223/https://docs.docker.com/installation/windows/#uninstallation) (*1) says:

> You can uninstall Boot2Docker using Window’s standard process for removing programs.

This means that it must be writing a entry to the Uninstall key in the registry.

They [seem](https://github.com/boot2docker/windows-installer/blob/master/Boot2Docker.iss) to be using Inno Setup and if I'm interpreting their script correctly then the uninstallation information should be in `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{05BD04E9-4AB5-46AC-891E-60EA8FD57D56}_is1` where you could probably read the `InstallLocation` value with `ReadRegStr` or parse the `UninstallString` value but you should verify this in Regedit. Also remember that if this information is written to the 64-bit part of the registry then you need to use `SetRegView` in your NSIS script to read it.

---

*1: Linking to archive.org because Boot2Docker is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try.

Comment: Thanks . It worked . ReadRegStr $0 HKLM "Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${appID}_is1" "UninstallString"

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get the application path of another application unless you know something about it.  If it is a previous version and you wrote it, you should have it in the previous installer.  Otherwise you would need to check the registry to find something unique about the old application, then use that in your NSIS script, or simply ask the user.